# Stata bar charts with dates

Tags: stata

I'm trying to create a bar chart with a time axis. This is the code that I'm using:

```
twoway (bar weeksum week)
```

The `week` variable is a time variable and has the format `%td`.

However, when I create the bar chart, the X axis does not follow the format specified for the `week` variable. Instead the X axis takes integer values. I was wondering whether there is a way to fix this.

Comment: Please read and work from http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in Stata 13.1. The format of the time variable is used by default on the time (horizontal) axis.

Here's a test script. Hint: You should learn to produce such reproducible examples yourself.

```
clear 
input week weeksum 
20093  16
20100  61 
20107  34  
20114  42
20121  24 
end
format week %td 
levelsof week, local(levels) 
twoway bar weeksum week, base(0) barw(6) xla(`levels', noticks)
```